# How to set custom trigger rule in Airflow?

Tags: triggers, airflow

Is there any way to configure the custom trigger rules in airflow?

Find below a sample case of my problem statement:

**Let's suppose I have 4 tasks with the below lineage(dependencies):**

```
[Task1, Task2, Task3] >> Task4
```

Here I want to trigger **`Task4`** only when **`Task1`** **failed** and **`Task2`** and **`Task3`** get **Succeed**.

I am aware of the possible [trigger_rule](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules) provided by airflow. But did not get any rule that can handle the above scenario. Is there any workaround or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no existing rule to do that, but there are some simple solutions to achieve your goal:

1. Add an EmptyOperator (DummyOperator) task between Task1 and Task4 with rule `all_failed`:

   ```py
   Task1 >> Empty  
   [Empty, Task2, Task3] >> Task4
   ```

   In this case Empty will not be triggered if Task1 is `success`.
2. Add a ShortCircuitOperator task before Task4 to check the state of the other tasks:
   You can check the state of the 3 tasks with a simple python method, then decide if you want to trigger Task4 or not:

   ```py
   def get_state(task_id, **context):
       return context["dag_run"].get_task_instance(task_id).state

   ShortCircuitOperator(
       task_id="check_logic",
       python_callable=lambda: get_state("Task1") == "failed" and get_state("Task2") == "success" and get_state("Task3") == "success",
       provide_context=True,
   )
   ```