# Airflow trigger rule, all but one has succeeded

Tags: python, airflow

I'm new to Airflow. Is there an Airflow trigger rule (or a custom rule) that if all but one upstream tasks have succeeded (the remaining one is still running), the task will trigger?

How about trigger rule for when a certain proportion of the upstream tasks have succeeded, say 80% (to the closest integer of course)?

Comment: you can create an EmptyOperator that the tasks that need to be success would connect it and then set trigger_rule= one_success to the next task. if you can add code or diagram I can explain it specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you did something like this...

1. Start with a set of tasks T_i, and the downstream task D.
2. For each task in the set of tasks succeeds, create a downstream dependent task PythonOperator that checks the states across T. If at least 80% of the tasks succeed, return a success. Otherwise fail.
3. Mark D as downstream of all the PythonOperator tasks. Set the `trigger_rule='one_success'`. Therefore if any of the PythonOperators succeed (knowing that 80% of the tasks have succeeded) then D succeeds.

Rough idea in code (taking inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73458355/how-to-set-custom-trigger-rule-in-airflow))

Suppose you have a list of tasks and the downstream task:

```
tasks = [
    task_1
    task_2
    ...
    task_n
]


downstream_task = EmptyOperator()
```

```
def succeed_if_80pct_succeeds(tasks, **context):
    states = [context["dag_run"].get_task_instance(t.task_id).state for t in tasks]
    num_success = states.count("success")
    if num_success >= round(len(states) * 0.8):
         return True
    return False

success_checks = []

for t in tasks:
    p = PythonOperator(
         python_callable=succeed_if_80pct_succeeds,
         provide_context=True,
    )
    t >> p
    success_checks.append(p)

continue_after_80pct_check = EmptyOperator(trigger_rule='one_success')

success_checks >> continue_after_80pct_check >> downstream_task
```